# Clojure: How to run complex DB migration in production?

Tags: java, clojure, jvm, flyway

Imagine you have a task to perform a complex DB migration as part of a new version release into production, how would you usually do it in a Clojure project?

An example for a new "big" release, migrations:

- **V1__create_new_tables** (easy, just use vanilla SQL with CREATE TABLE)
- **V2__perform_complex_migration** (CREATE TABLE foo, loop through another table and fill in new `foo` table with some data using custom Clojure code)
- **V3__do_something_else** (easy, could be another simple SQL query

How would you do that 2nd migration in an automated way? All 3 migrations have to be executed in order for a new release to be successful.

Looks like [Flyway DB has Java migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#java-based-migrations) which looks like exactly what is needed but is there any way to use it from Clojure?

Perhaps one can add another `.clj` file [along with other `.sql` migrations](https://github.com/metaphor/lein-flyway/tree/master/example/src-resources/db/migration) and Flyway would pick it up?

I'm a bit surprised I can't any examples for what seems like a very common task in Clojure, only simple SQL queries.

Comment: Checkout Migratus. It allows you to have plain sql and clojure code based migrations. https://github.com/yogthos/migratus#code-based-migrations So for your V2 migration, you would use code based migration.

Comment: @blushrt Thanks! If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [Migratus README](https://github.com/yogthos/migratus#defining-a-code-based-migration):

> Defining a code-based migration
>
> Create a code-based migration by adding a .edn file to your migrations
> directory that contains the namespace and up/down functions to run,
> e.g. resources/migrations/20170331141500-import-users.edn:

```
{:ns app.migrations.import-users
 :up-fn migrate-up
 :down-fn migrate-down}
```

> Then, in src/app/migrations/import_users.clj:

```clj
(ns app.migrations.import-users)

(defn migrate-up [config]
;; do stuff here
)

(defn migrate-down [config]    
;; maybe undo stuff here
)
```

> The up and down migration functions should both accept a single parameter,
> which is the config map passed to Migratus (so your migrations can be
> configurable). You can omit the up or down migration by setting :up-fn
> or down-fn to nil in the EDN file.